# Yaml file for CloudFormation - select which subnet ids to put lambdas in

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, github-actions, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to put my lambdas in the appropriate VPC given the environment. How can that be achieved given I'm building the VPCs in a separate nested stack given the environment?

Using Github actions and `sam deploy` if that matters.

```
Parameters:
  environment:
    Type: String
  devLambdaSubnetIds:
    Type: String
    Default: !Join [',', subnet-[devVpcA], subnet-[devVpcB]]
  prodLambdaSubnetIds:
    Type: String
    Default: !Join [',', subnet-[prodVpcA], subnet-[prodVpcB]]
...
Resources:
 HealthCheckFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
        ...
        VpcConfig:
        Ipv6AllowedForDualStack: false
        SecurityGroupIds: 
          - !Ref genericSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds: HERE THIS NEEDS TO BE !Ref devLambdaSubnetIds or !Ref prodLambdaSubnetIds depending on the environment (which is either 'dev' or 'prod')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mapping and keep config for each env in the mapping.

In the example below the subnet ids would need to be changed for real subnet ids.

```
Parameters:
  env:
    Type: String
    Description: Specify an account/environment
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - prod

Mappings:
  environments:
    dev:
      sb1: subnet-a
      sb2: subnet-b
    prod:
      sb1: subnet-c
      sb2: subnet-d

Resources:
  HealthCheckFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      ...
      VpcConfig:
        Ipv6AllowedForDualStack: false
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref genericSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !FindInMap [environments, !Ref env, sb1]
          - !FindInMap [environments, !Ref env, sb2]
```

You could alternately store the subnet ids in param store at paths like;

```
/myapp/dev/subnet1
/myapp/dev/subnet2
/myapp/prod/subnet1
/myapp/prod/subnet2
```

Then, reference them in your template like this;

```
          - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/myapp/${env}/subnet1}}'
          - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/myapp/${env}/subnet2}}'
```

You could use conditions as well.

```
Conditions:
  IsDevEnvironment: !Equals [!Ref env, 'dev']
```

Then add in the condition to the resource. You would need two distinct resources, one for dev and one for prod then, though.

```
  HealthCheckFunctionDevelopment:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Condition: IsDevEnvironment
    Properties:
      ...
      VpcConfig:
        Ipv6AllowedForDualStack: false
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref genericSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet1-harcoded
          - subnet2-harcoded
```